# Button click event Android studio multiple XML files

Tags: android

The following Java code on Android studio permits the application to take pictures continuously:

```
@Override

public synchronized void onResume() {

LOGGER.d("onResume " + this);
super.onResume();

    handlerThread = new HandlerThread("inference");
    handlerThread.start();
    handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

}
```

If I remove this code from the camera_activity Java file, the application don't take pictures at all and the camera is just started.

What I want to do is to insert a button in the layout design and if clicked the resume code is executed and so I take the picture.

The problem is that the project is very complex and I must do in this way if I don't want to modify too many other parameters.

I've tried to use the:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
});
```

But the button is inserted in an XML file which isn't imported via the "setContentView" command and can't be inserted in the XML imported from the camera_activity file and so the above code can't run without problems.

Is there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: hard to follow you without any more code. 
Assuming you can add the button in your layout, you can just define a boolean in your activity and set it to false in onCreate. Then, you'll set it to true when the button is clicked, and the thread will be started only if the boolean is set to true

Comment: The code is all in here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tree/master/android/tfmobile The problem is with the file in res/layout/activity_camera.xml which is included in the java file in src/org/tensorflow/demo/camera_activity and can't permit me to create a button because the camera_activity.xml is a frame_layout. What do you think is needed in order to create a button in a different layout and creating connection with the camera_activity java file?

Comment: I've tried to put a botton in the file activity_camera.xml but the result was that it isn't able to recognize the botton's touch. So I really need to create the button in a different layout file but I don't know how to add it to the camera_activity java file.